# Find probablity that player A go bankrupt (of Markov chain)

Tags: probability

PLayers $A$ and B play in following game:
With prob=$p$ player $A$ loses one coin, then player $B$ get one coin. With prob = $q$ player $B$ loses one coin and player $A$ get one coin. At begin they have $m$ coins together, where player $A$ has $j$ coins. ($j=1,2,...,m-1$)
What is probablity that player $A$ go bankrupt ?

[image]
So according to my drawing we have following equations:  $f_{a,b}$ denotes probablity that we start in $a$ and end in $b$
$f_{m,0}=0$
$f_{0,0}=1 $
$f_{j,0}=pf_{j+1,0}+qf_{j-1, 0}$
$f_{j+1, 0} = pf_{j+2,0}+qf_{j,0}$
$f_{j-1, 0}=pf_{j,0} + qf_{j-2, 0} $
$...$

Could you help me ?

Comment: If they stop playing when there is a bankrupt, there is an arrow too much in the diagram. Anyway, are you looking for the probability that $A$ goes bankrupt in a certain number of steps or just *sooner or later*?

Comment: sooner or later. Why is it to much arrows ?

Comment: If $A$ goes bankrupt they stop playing, so there is no green arrow exiting from the pink state. For the same reason, many arrows have to be switched: from any non-terminal state, we must go with probability $p$ somewhere and with probability $q$ somewhere else, while there are two red arrows marked with a $q$ exiting from the initial state.

Comment: Ok, I edited my post, look again

Comment: There is a simple and nice solution via martingales. Do you know something about martingales?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $S_0$ be the state in which $A$ goes bankrupt and $S_m$ be the state in which $B$ goes bankrupt. Let we consider the transition matrix $M$ of the Markov chain: for any state different from $S_0$ and $S_m$, we go in the next state with probability $p$ and in the previous state with probability $q$; in $S_0$ and $S_m$ we stay there with probability $1$. Since $M$ is an irreducible stochastic  matrix, we can read our probability in $M^\infty$ applied to the vector $(0,0,\ldots,1,0,0,\ldots,0)$, with a $1$ in the $(j+1)$-th position, corresponding to the initial configuration. $S_0$ and $S_m$ are absorbing states.
Can you say something about the eigenvalues/eigenvectors of $M$? Can you finish from there?

Comment: Ok, I see that u use Matrix. Is it possilbe to make it without matrix ? Because now I don't know matrix

Comment: @xaweyNEW:  In such a case, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin , *unfair coin*.